# Pandas Dataframe empty value's type issue

Tags: python, nan

Let's say there's an empty cell in a data frame.
If I print out the type of the empty cell, It prints out:

```
<class 'float'> nan
```

Why does it print out the type as class 'float'?

And if a cell has nan value in a cell and the other cell has empty, can I handle these two cells as same as NaN value in it?

Comment: Seems that missing data is represented as NaNs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data What does the "empty" cell look like, can you give an example of how to create such an empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NaN is a special value which is part of the IEEE floating-point
specification. Hence, when you will check the type of NaN it will show it as a float.

The empty cell will be using Pythonic Missing data value i.e. None, so it is advisable to use pandas.fillna for comparing two cells.